# Issue interacting with Omdb API on live site

Tags: javascript, reactjs

WEBSITE NOT WORKING WHEN HOSTED!

> Mixed Content: The page at 'omdbapi-app1.vercel.app/results?movieName=spider' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'omdbapi.com/?apikey=8e70dc5&s=spider'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Site: https://omdbapi-app.vercel.app

This API was working on my localhost. But I don't know why not working on that web site.

Comment: What are the errors you get? How do you call the API inside your development environment?

Comment: Mixed Content: The page at 'https://omdbapi-app1.vercel.app/results?movieName=spider' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=8e70dc5&s=spider'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Comment: https://github.com/gokmenozkn/omdbapi-app It's the github repo.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you call the API via HTTP Protocol. Try calling your API via HTTPS instead of HTTP

```
https://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=<YOUR_API_KEY>&s=spider
```

Replace `<YOUR_API_KEY>` with the real API Key

Comment: Please consider approving the answer if it helped :)

Answer (score 1):

When using platforms like `CodeSandbox` or `hosting on other websites`, it's essential to employ `HTTPS` instead of `HTTP`. Local development often relies on `HTTP`, an insecure protocol. However, websites use `HTTPS`, providing a secure connection. Therefore, it's crucial to access the API via "`HTTPS`"

```js
const APIKey = 'your_API_key'; // Replace this with your actual API key
const query = 'your_search_query'; // Replace this with what you want to search

const apiUrl = `https://www.omdbapi.com/?i=tt3896198&apikey=${APIKey}&s=${query}`;
```